# Где посмотреть логи работы NodeJS-PushServer?

Tags: сеть, битрикс24

В коробочной версии Битрикс 24 то работает p&p то не работает. Тех. поддержка продукта ссылается на сеть. Выводя логи на экран терминала (journalctl -f) ошибок нет. Пинговал и трассеровал - ошибок или потерь нет. Как посмотреть или узнать в чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь логи `nginx`- `/var/log/nginx/`

Во вторую очередь логи самого `push-server` - `/var/log/push-server/`